# Request-Response with the ask pattern

Tags: scala, akka

I am fairly new to Akka and went through [this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#request-response-with-ask-between-two-actors) request-response example of the Akka documentation.

I understood this pattern works like the following:

1. `Dave` asks `Hal` by sending a message of `Hal`'s protocol.
2. `Hal` answers by sending a message of its own protocol to `Dave`.
3. `Dave`, who does not know `Hal`'s protocol gets the response adapted and re-sent to itself.
4. `Dave` receives the adapted response and continues with its payload.

```
context.ask(dave, Dave.Request) {
  case Failure(exception) => throw exception
  case Success(response) => AdaptedResponse(response.payload)
}
```

But what happens, if `Dave` needs `response.payload` diretly on the spot? Is this even possible?

Comment: if you want to get response back to the actor who is doing the ask it can be done using ask followed by the forward and then pipe to sender, provided that the processing time should not be more than as timeout.

Answer (score 0):

In Akka Typed, it's not possible using `context.ask`, though I would question why you specifically need it.

As an alternative, when you have two actors which interact, you can define a joint-protocol between them:

```
object Hal {
  sealed trait Command

  sealed trait CommandFromDave extends Command {
    def replyTo: ActorRef[Dave.ResponseFromHal]
  }

  case class OpenThePodBayDoorsPlease(override val replyTo: ActorRef[Dave.ResponseFromHal]) extends CommandFromDave
}

object Dave {
  sealed trait Command

  sealed trait ResponseFromHal extends Command

  case class MessageFromHal(msg: String) extends ResponseFromHal
}
```

Then `Dave` can just

```
hal ! Hal.CommandFromDave(context.self)
```

and get the response directly from `Hal` (and you can schedule a message to yourself to account for the timeout).

Note that this really entangles two actors together.  It's suitable for cases like where a parent actor defers a long-running task to a child actor, but it's a really questionable approach in most/all other scenarios.